# Load data from model to line chart

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I have a view of a web page. This web page contain a line chart that load data from the model. My senior suggest using "var myJSON = JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));" to pass the value from the model but I dont know how to get the needed data as the model have many data field.

Code at model:

```
namespace CORE.Views
{
    public class V_ReportTransaction : BusinessObject
    {
        public double TotalAmount { get; set; }
        public int OrgId { get; set; }
        public string TimeCheck { get; set; }
        public string Service { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Code at view:

```
@using CORE.Helpers;
@model List<CORE.Views.V_ReportTransaction>


<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; margin: auto">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>


<script>

    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));


    var RevenueCanvas = document.getElementById("chart");

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;

var RevenueData = {
  labels: [], //TimeCheck field 
  datasets: [{
    label: "Total Revenue",
    data: [], //totalAmount field
  }]
};

var chartOptions = {
  legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'top',
    labels: {
      boxWidth: 80,
      fontColor: 'black'
    }
  }
};

    var lineChart = new Chart(RevenueCanvas, {
  type: 'line',
    data: RevenueData,
  options: chartOptions
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your myJSON should be containing x, y as { x : 1, y : 2 }  where x and y works as x axis and y axis where you wish to draw your graph.

Comment: i cant seem to do it inside script tag